# Why is my computer not updating via Windows Update?

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, windows-sbs, wsus

I just recently installed Windows 8 Pro on a computer at work. The computer runs Windows Update fine while its not joined to the domain. However, once I join it to the domain it cannot perform windows update.

I get the following error code `800B0001` when it tries to update.

Also in the `WindowsUpdate.log` I see that I get the following error.

```
Validating signature for C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\SelfUpdate\wuident.cab:
Microsoft signed: Yes
Infrastructure signed: No
WARNING: Digital Signatures on file C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\SelfUpdate\wuident.cab are not trusted: Error 0x800b0001
WARNING: SelfUpdate check failed to download package information, error = 0x800B0001
FATAL: SelfUpdate check failed, err = 0x800B0001
WARNING: Skipping scan, self-update check returned 0x800B0001
WARNING: Exit code = 0x800B0001
```

We have a Windows SBS Server 2008 running WSUS. All other Windows 7 machines are working just fine. I notice that it can't verify the signature of the `.cab`. Do I need to manually accept a server certificate somewhere?

**EDIT 1**

Oddly enough I went and spun up a new Windows 8 machine and joined the domain. It was able to receive updates from

**Control Panel->Windows Update**

but was not able to receive updates from

**(Win + i) -> Change PC Settings -> Windows Update**.

Comment: After you joined the Domain, can it still list the updates with the KB hotlinks for manual download or does it fail to even get that far? I'm not asking just to hint that I know your answer, this is for myself to help me and others avoid the time consuming precaution of imaging my box, joining a domain just to realize there is no more way to even dowload the fixes that I'm willing to individually click and load or if WindowsUPdate is just ruined until I restore my image.

Comment: not really sure on this one I will have to check tomorrow and get back to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be that WSUS needs to be updated to manage Windows 8 clients.  This was an issue with Windows 7 clients and WSUS and an update fixed the issue. A. Not sure that there is an update to support Windows 8 at this point but one MS forum indicates that KB2734608 addreses the issue.  Later it indicates that fix is not available but points to other updates.  [WSUS Discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverwsus/thread/9f6e3665-6b72-4cd3-abdd-b9f551280acc)

Comment: Finally got the chance to update WSUS, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install [KB2720211](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2720211) on the WSUS server. Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverwsus/thread/8ebfbc1e-06e5-43c5-a540-1ca37c6ffff9/